# hide when push view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, keyboard

When I tap the go button on the keyboard I push to a new view controller, but for a split second on the new view controller the old keyboard is still showing, how can I resign the keyboard so it doesn't appear on the new view controller I have tried both

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

And this

```
[_passwordField resignFirstResponder];
```

in the `prepareForSegue` method and the same two lines in the `IBAction`

Comment: Have you tried using the textfield delegate method ->     -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField and dismiss there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have first tying to push to a new view controller, after that you are code for hide keyboard. Use following code for your problem, use this delegate method **textFieldShouldReturn**.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     if ( textField ==  _passwordField){
          [_passwordField resignFirstResponder];
          //After that Push to a new view controller From Here
     }
     return TRUE;
}
```